# Interpret/parse Javascript Variables in c# with JInt or similar

Tags: c#, jint

I'm attempting to build an application that uses an API that was made for JavaScript.  Rather than sending down JSON or XML it sends a Script tag with a JavaScript object within it like so:

```
<script>
var apiresult = {
    success: true,
    data: {
        userName: "xxxxx",
        jsonData: { 
            "id" : "8342859",
            "price" : "83.94"
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I'm trying to get out just the "jsonData" property.  In browser land you can go:

```
apiresult.data.jsonData;
```

Obviously I can't do this in C#.  I've tried using Jint and HtmlAgilityPack like so:

```
HtmlDocument = await client.GetHTMLAsync(url);

string scriptTag = htmlResult.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").InnerHtml;

scriptTag += " return apiresult.data.jsonData;

JintEngine engine = new JintEngine();

Jint.Native.JsObject r = (Jint.Native.JsObject)engine.Run(scriptTag);
```

And if I expand "r.Results" in the watch window it shows the variables values, but how do I then get just the raw JSON back out so that I can parse it into my object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I used [jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com) to do this.  Much much easier to use than JInt.  My code now looks like this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngine();

object result = engine.Evaluate(scriptString);

var json = Jurassic.Library.JSONObject.Stringify(engine, result);
```

Answer (score 5):

I hit the same problem, here is how I did it with Jint

```
        var engine =new Engine();

        var html = 
                    @"<script>
                        var apiresult = {
                            success: true,
                            data: {
                                userName: ""xxxxx"",
                                jsonData: { 
                                    ""id"" : ""8342859"",
                                    ""price"" : ""83.94""
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                    </script>";


        var doc=new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var script = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script").First().InnerHtml;

        var result = engine
            .Execute(script)
            .Execute("var x=apiresult.data.jsonData;")
            .GetValue("x");

        var jsonData = engine.Json.Stringify(result, new[] { result });
```